# How to count total number of divs with in a div using CSS

Tags: css

Is there a way to count the total number of divs within a div using CSS?

So far I have developed a solution using JavaScript.

```
$('#nextPrev > div').length
```

But I just wondered whether this is possible to do via CSS.

Comment: You can't get count with CSS only :)

Comment: There is no way to count or perform tasks like this in CSS. You can select elements and apply style rules to them. You will have to use Javascript for this.

Comment: Not possible. But why would you wan't to?

Comment: use `var nb = $('div.name').length;`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a [css counter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Counters) to get the count.  Consider the following html:

```
<div id="test">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div id="result"></div>
```

You can display the count using the following css:

```
#test {counter-reset:test;}
#test > div {counter-increment:test;}
#result:before {content:counter(test);}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/QGXEX/)

Comment: I completely forgot about the counter.